# redirection with jsf - from a page in web to a page in WEB-INF

Tags: redirect, jsf-2, web-inf

I would like to redirect from a page in webapp/index to a page in WEB-INF/user.xhtml
How can I do that in jsf ?

regards,

Answer (score 0):

The WEB-INF folder is not destinated for web files: `.xhtml`,`.jsf`,etc. But rather for template files that haven't to be targeted directly and couldn't be.